# Will an overheating engine result in higher rpm?

Tags: overheating, rpm

A mechanic claimed that one of the telltale signs of overheating is a noticeable increase in engine's rpm, among other signs including weak engine's performance etc.

I have made several searches but I couldn't find any results that support his claim.

Technically, I couldn't find a logical connection that overheating causes an increase in rpm.

Is that claim true? And if so why?

Comment: I don't have anything "definitive", but I've never seen a higher rpm occur due to overheating. Besides that, it doesn't actually make much sense to my pea brain.

Comment: Same here! .....

Comment: Surely logically it is the opposite.  The tolerances go out of bonk and you can't get peak revs.  But I too haven't seen anything to prove it.

Comment: I discussed the issue with him an hour ago or so. It turned out he was mistaken or wasn't precise. His answer was when an engine overheats a problem could happen to a sensor that would give an erratic reading to the ECU and  that may cause the ECU to raise the RPM.

Comment: "... *a problem could happen to a sensor* ..." ... Even that doesn't make much sense and the possibility would be very remote. I'm going to call "myth busted" on the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have any empirical evidence, but I do have some understanding of how modern engines work. Due to this, I can tell you what your mechanic stated cannot actually be true. The reason is, in modern ECUs which controls how the engine runs, there is a setting which is called "Target RPM". This is a setting which tells the ECU how fast to run the engine at idle. Once the engine/system is warmed up, this is the RPM it tries to keep the engine at when there's no input from the driver (ie: depressing the go pedal). Even if there were *issues* with the engine due to whatever reason, including overheating, the ECU is still going to try and maintain that RPM at idle. This applies even if the engine is having issues up and until the point where the engine cannot run at all, at which point it quits running.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the engine idle speed is kept at the minimum stable point so it does not stall .For this to happen the torque produced is in balance with the total torque losses like bearing and bore friction.As the engine slowly cooks the oil will lose some of its friction reducing properties and clearances will start to tighten up .This means more friction so more torque needed so more engine idle rpm.